# "there was no bearing with it"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Here is a quote from an historical article on the dissolution of monasteries by Henry VIII :

> Henry did not resettle. He plundered and broke. He used the fetish of
> executive power just as much at Reading or in the Blackfriars of
> London, where unthinking and immediate popular feeling was with him,
> as at Glastonbury where it was against him, as in Yorkshire where it
> was in arms, as in Galway where **there was no bearing with it** at
> all.

I am unsure about the meaning of the part which I put in bold. Does bearing mean "toleration" (in which case it would mean that people in Galway couldn't stand Henry VIII) or "relevance, connection" (in which case it would mean that popular feeling was indifferent to Henry VIII in Galway)?

Also, I've never seen the syntax "there is no bearing with" before, I'm a little bit puzzled by it and a little bit of explanation would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, *it* should refer to *popular feeling*, but it seems to me that the author has lost their way in the sentence and means that the people of Galway couldn't bear to accept the dissolution of their monasteries.

I'd never thought about Ireland in this context before, but according to [this](https://midletonwith1d.wordpress.com/category/dissolution-of-the-irish-monasteries/) attempts *were* made to close the Irish monasteries, but were far less successful than those in England and Wales.

Comment: Also, "bear with" means enduring, being patient : "Bear with me" means "Be patient with me, I've a lot to say." Thanks for the historical context (which is also why I accept this answer rather than the other one).

Answer (score 0):

**Bearing** has the same meaning as in "bear the brunt" and "bear up". It means to endure an unpleasant hardship, or to persevere under a great burden. Martyrs have a heavy "cross to bear".

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bear+the+brunt+(of+something)
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bear+up
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+cross+to+bear

The idiom "there was no bearing with (it)" is exaggerated humor, suggesting the King's existence was just too great of a burden for the people of Galway to endure.

Comment: So "it" refers to the King's existence here ? I thought it referred to "popular feeling", as in the preceding parts of the sentence

Comment: @EwanDelanoy You think the "popular feeling" itself was unbearable...? No, it was the *King* that was unbearable. The phrase breaks the sentence pattern for humor.